# activate more than a user at once

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on my project for my school, I made activating a user account work, if the admin want to activate one user at a time, 
but whenever the admin wants to update multiple record at once, it won't work
I tried to include the update SQL inside a foreach loop, but it gave me an error: invalid argument for foreach()
pleas guys help me,

```
 if(isset($_POST['activate'] )){
$impid = implode(',', $_POST['SSU']);

// for each .. to update more than one at once. 
foreach($impid AS $i){
$sql = "UPDATE Accounts SET Activated = '".$_POST['activate']."' WHERE SSU IN('" . $i . "') ";
$result = mysqli_query($dbCIE, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));
                            }

 //  to test. if anything got effected.. 
 if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbCIE) > 0) {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Successfully Updated ')</script>";
          }
    else {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Failed to  Update ')</script>";
            } // end the test. 

      }else{echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert(' Select Whether to Activare Or Deactive ')</script>";}
     }
     } // end of first if $_post[update]
```

Comment: `implode` returns a string, so you can't (and indeed don't need to) pass it into foreach.

Comment: thank u sir, I just fixed  it

Comment: How your $i looks like

Comment: This is open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

thank u guys, I fixed it, i just passed `$_POST['SSU']` to my foreach and it worked.